# How to get Operating System version and name in Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I am currently developing a GMail addon and it requires some Operating System related information. The kind of information we get when we run 'Navigator.UserAgent'

I can determine some/partial data using the event parameter 'clientPlatform'. But it does not have the more verbose information found in `Navigator.UserAgent`.

I also tried `HtmlService.getUserAgent()` but it returned null.

Is there a way to get 'userAgent'-like properties from Google Apps Scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#getuseragent

> getUserAgent()
>
> Gets the user-agent string for the current browser. Returns null for most script executions if not used in a web app's doGet() or doPost() function.

In other words, it's not possible on Gmail-Addons only on Web Apps.

Comment: Thanks @Rubén for the quick and definitive response.